# Text is not set vertically center in entry control for mac and iOS platform in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

I am using an entry control of Xamarin.Forms for the iOS and Mac platforms. The problem I have is that I can control the horizontal alignment but not the vertical. I want to vertically center the text in the entry control but I am not able to do so.

I haven't found any solution for Xamarin but I did find a few [links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34381410/) in Swift or Objective-C. So, I converted this code to C# and it doesn't work.

The below code is in the Mac renderer for my entry:

```cs
 var newRect =new CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: 30, height: 30);
 Control.Cell.DrawingRectForBounds(newRect); //NSTextField
```

This doesn't change the UI.

Can you please tell me how to set text vertically center in Mac and iOS project?

Comment: Could you show image or some code in xaml .If setting `<Entry Text="hello" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Aqua"/>` this,  I can get this screen here.It seems like is center vertically.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcYpa.png

Comment: True, but if you increase height of text box then it not vertically center align.

Comment: Link : https://imgur.com/a/hMba9Ng

Comment: Okey, there is a way to set in IOS project.

Answer (score 0):

Set UiTextField Text Vertical Center in renderer as bellow:

```
Control.VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center; //Control: UiTextField
```

[UIControlContentVerticalAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uicontrolcontentverticalalignment?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

Even not set this , I found this default is vertical center in IOS, maybe somewhere your project change something.

```
<local:MyEntry Placeholder="placeholder" HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for iOS comment. I need solution for mac platform. in mac , Control.Alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center; property available for horizontal alignment but no any property available for vertical alignment.

Comment: you can refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775128/set-text-vertical-center-in-nstextfield for more information.

Comment: @JohnSmith Okey, thanks for link.This will be helpful for me too. :)