# How to make NSTextField use custom subclass of NSTextFieldCell?

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I've been looking for a solution to make my NSTextField bottom-aligned and I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236659/1016508) and adjusted it for my needs. So now I have this custom NSTextFieldCell but how do I tell my NSTextFields to use this class (programmatically)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setCell: method of the NSControl class?

```
- (void)setCell:(NSCell *)aCell
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you ask how to do it programmatically, you can also use the `setCellClass:` method on your `NSTextField` subclass. Call it in the `load` or `initialize` class methods:

```
+(void)load
{
    [self setCellClass:[MyTextFieldCell class]];
}
```

It will not have any bearing on your text fields defined in Interface Builder, as the text field cell set there takes precedence.

Comment: looks like it's removed now :(