# NSControl's setCellClass is deprecated in OS X 10.10 what's the alternative for overriding NSTextField's cell class?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I'm attempting to follow the post linked below to override the NSCell of a NSTextField but it looks like the `setCellClass` method is now deprecated in OSX 10.10.

[How to make NSTextField use custom subclass of NSTextFieldCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293071/how-to-make-nstextfield-use-custom-subclass-of-nstextfieldcell)

How should one override the NSTextField's cell substituting it for a subclass?

The reason for doing this is to vertically centre the text of a NSTextField cell which Apple have made very difficult.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```swift
public override class var cellClass: AnyClass? { get { YourCustomCell.self } set {} }
```

on the `NSControl` subclass seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: don't.  As per [the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#X10_10Notes), NSCell itself is being 'gradually deprecated'.

To vertically align some text, you can use layout constraints.  Depending on the situation, you might need to put the NSTextField inside a larger NSView.